# FD02 - dynpro does not exist

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I am running transaction FD02, and when I put a specific client number it triggers a dump (`DYNPRO_NOT_FOUND`, see image).

I tried to search for notes using the terms given below but I could not get any relevant info.

```
"DYNPRO_NOT_FOUND" " "
"SAPLSZA1" or " "
"SYSTEM-EXIT"
```

What needs to be done to avoid the dump? The other clients works fine, only one does not.
[image: Dump]
Thanks.

Comment: Run transaction `SE38` and copy paste us the code of the program `SAPLSZA1`. This way someone could be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that the other clients work but one in particular does not, then the problem might be in a customizing table. I assume that the screen number is read from some kind of a configuration table and for the client you are testing on, those entries have not been provided.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has to be investigated in your system. If you don't have the knowledge for yourself, you should report this via SAPnet. SYSTEM-EXIT suggests that it's a problem with some kind of additional programming, but from the info you give it's impossible to determine exactly what is going wrong.